# jQuery-Ajax get width of Image inside of Ajax-Container

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have created a page with Ajax function (jQuery & PHP).
My problem is when I load content via Ajax in my page. I want to read  width of images placed inside of Ajax-container.

I noticed something quite remarkable.

My script:

```
<script>
 $(window).ready(function () {
  var bildBreite = $("#wrapper > #target-image").width();
   alert(bildBreite);
  $("#wrapper > #image-wrapper").css({"width": bildBreite});
 });
</script>
```

It does not work, but when I insert alert ("load"); then work it.

```
<script>
 $(window).ready(function () {
  alert("Load");
  var bildBreite = $("#wrapper > #target-image").width();
   alert(bildBreite);
  $("#wrapper > #image-wrapper").css({"width": bildBreite});
 });
</script>
```

What happens here, how can I read the image width?

Comment: How are you calling your ajax? Can you also show those code?

Comment: <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
  var id = '1';
  
  $('#button').click(function() {
  
 $.ajax({
  
  dataType:"html",
  type: "POST",
  cache:false,
  async: true,
  data: "seite=" + id,
  url: "verzeichnis/script.php",
  success: function(breite) {
  $("#result").html(breite);
        var width = $('#result img').width();
        alert(width);
  }
 });
  });  });
  
  </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you need success callback because AJAX is Asynchronous so on Window Load it will not the get the element width so try it like,

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success:function (response) {
       var bildBreite = $("#wrapper > #target-image").width();
       $("#wrapper > #image-wrapper").css({"width": bildBreite});
    }
});
```

Read more about [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thank you for your solution but, i have a little problem with it. I should push the Button two times! Befor i get a image size do you know why??? Thank you!

Comment: If your AJAX call is working in a single click then you don't need to click it twice. See in your browser's console when you click on button and make sure XHR request is made or not.

Comment: if a cache is clean and i click on the button my first value is 0 if i click again i get a right value.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  
  var id = '1';
  
 $.ajax({
  
  dataType:"html",
  type: "POST",
  cache:false,
  async: true,
  data: "seite=" + id,
  url: "verzeichnis/script.php",
  success: function(breite) {
  $("#result").html(breite);
        var width = $('#result img').width();
        alert(width);
  }
 });
  });

Comment: where is click event in this code

Comment: <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
  var id = '1';
  
  $('#button').click(function() {
  
 $.ajax({
  
  dataType:"html",
  type: "POST",
  cache:false,
  async: true,
  data: "seite=" + id,
  url: "verzeichnis/script.php",
  success: function(breite) {
  $("#result").html(breite);
        var width = $('#result img').width();
        alert(width);
  }
 });
  });  });
  
  </script>